# Cake burnt on top using both elements on top and bottom.

Tags: baking, brownies

Should I use only the bottom element for heating when baking cakes and brownies??

Comment: As a note, if you're using American recipes, *most* American ovens don't allow for both the upper and lower elements to run simultaneously... you chose either "bake" (lower elements) or "broil" (grill in the UK, upper elements).

Comment: My oven has a "Roast" setting which turns on both top and bottom. "Bake"  is only the bottom.

Comment: I tried it again with only the bottom element. Wonderful chewy perfect brownies. Thank You.

Comment: @Catija Strange, I always put all of my cakes on top and bottom at the same time. If I forget it and turn on only one, the cake fails. And I have been baking many American recipes in recent years.

Comment: @rumtscho Is it possible that the strength of your upper element is different/more variable? Upper elements here tend to be pretty direct heat. It's also possible the OP was doing something else like using the upper rack?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I would suggest you only use the bottom element when baking the actual cake. Using both elements is generally used for pre-heating the oven, or to brown the top of a dish. Maybe use the top element to bring the oven up to temperature, then turn it off when you put the cake/brownies in the oven.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your oven and how bad the result is.

I suggest making different tries:

1. use only the bottom element
2. use both element and cover your cake with foil when you have the desired color on top to prevent over-cooking
3. use a pizza stone to keep an even temperature in your oven

I had the same problem and tried all those solutions. They all have pros and cons and depends on the result you want to achieve.